# How to get rid of Bar in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am new to developing but I have a problem

Here is the code of the stuff I believe you need to know

**Main Activity**

```
package com.mayubrand.basiccalculator;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements    View.OnClickListener {


private Button circumferenceB, areaB, diameterB;
private TextView resultTxt, radiusTxt, headingTxt;
private EditText radiusTF ;


public void onCreate(){
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();
}

private void init(){
    //Buttons
    circumferenceB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.circumferenceB);
    areaB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.areaB);
    diameterB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.diameterB);
    //Text Field (Edit Text)
    radiusTF = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.radiusTF);
    //Text (Text View)
    resultTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTxt);
    radiusTxt =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.radiusTxt);
    headingTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.radiusTxt);

    //==============
    //Listeners
    circumferenceB.setOnClickListener(this);
    areaB.setOnClickListener(this);
    diameterB.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    String radiusEntered = radiusTF.getText().toString();
    double pi = Math.PI;
    int two = 2;
    if(radiusEntered.equals("")) {
        radiusTF.setText("");
    }else{
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.circumferenceB:
                double circumference = Integer.parseInt(radiusEntered) * pi * two;
                resultTxt.setText(String.valueOf(circumference));
                break;
            case R.id.areaB:
                double area = pi * Integer.parseInt(radiusEntered) *Integer.parseInt(radiusEntered);
                resultTxt.setText(String.valueOf(area));
                break;
            case R.id.diameterB:
                double diameter = Integer.parseInt(radiusEntered) * 2;
                resultTxt.setText(String.valueOf(diameter));
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

}

**Main Activity XML**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="MayU Circle Calulator"
    android:id="@+id/headingTxt"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Radius"
    android:id="@+id/radiusTxt"
    android:layout_below="@+id/headingTxt"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:textSize="23dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/radiusTF"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/radiusTxt"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/headingTxt"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/headingTxt" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radiusTxt"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Find Circumference"
        android:id="@+id/circumferenceB"
        android:layout_weight="0.08" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Find Area"
        android:id="@+id/areaB"
        android:layout_weight="0.08" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Find Diameter"
        android:id="@+id/diameterB"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.08" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Result"
        android:id="@+id/resultTxt"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.08"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Android Manifest**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Circle Calculator"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"



    >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
   </application>

 </manifest>
```

When I'm in the layout area where you arrange all your buttons and text and any other component you have visually it looks fine, however as soon as I launch it in the emulator or on my phone there is a bar black/brown bar that just stays there. How do I remove that?

One other thing on the side, how do I change the default color of buttons

Comment: What type of bar are you referring to?? Can you post a Screenshot??

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are referring to the action bar.
If that is the case in your styles.xml change the AppTheme theme to NoActionBar.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

To change the default color of your buttons, you can use styles as well.